# How do I avoid capturing the primary group of a given regex pattern?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a regexp pattern:

```
<^(([a-z]+)\:([0-9]+)\/?.*)$>
```

How do I avoid capturing the primary group?

```
<^(?:([a-z]+)\:([0-9]+)\/?.*)$>
```

The above pattern will still put the whole string 'localhost:8080' into the first (0) group. But I need to get only 2 matched groups, so that first (0) group is populated with 'localhost' and second (1) with '8080'.

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Why are you using the outermost brackets?

Comment: But, why not? They are well supported and my actual pattern isn't expecting any of those chars.

Comment: Stuff inside brackets can get put into the matches array, which could be causing it were you not using PHP. Here, however, it's just an artefact of how PHP deals with the matching - the first match array item is always the whole thing, as the other posters have pointed out.

Comment: you might consider accepting one of the answers as the correct answer if we were able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [docs](https://www.php.net/preg_match):

> *matches*
>
> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

if you don't care about the full match, you can use [`array_shift()`](https://www.php.net/array_shift) to remove the unwanted element.

```
array_shift($matches);
```

Comment: Sigh, I see it now, I was reading the return value block. Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The first group, 0, will always be the entire match.

Answer (score 1):

That's just the way the regex functions work. The first group is always the entire match. You can use `array_shift` to get rid of it.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Comment: Thank you. I wish PHP reference for `preg_match` was more informative on return value of a pattern with multiple character groups.

Comment: @AleksandrMakov: it is. see my answer

Answer (score 1):

In a regex $0 is always equal to match string and not one of the groupings. Match groups will always start at $1. So look at $1 and $2 instead of $0 and $1.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with URLs, you can try using PEAR NetURL, or what might be better for you in this case would be [parse-url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

print_r(parse_url($url));